# List SSL certificates in c# (recreate IIS bindings dialog)

Tags: c#, iis, ssl-certificate

I am trying to list the SSL certs listed in the IIS bindings dialog box - but am unable to.  I'm dancing all around it, can anybody tell me where they are stored?  (My code snipped below isn't a 1:1 match - I can't figure out what store they are in).

[image]

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
foreach (var x in store.Certificates)
{
     radDropDownListIISCert.Items.Add(new RadListDataItem(x.FriendlyName, x.SerialNumber));
}
```

Comment: What is `StoreName.My`?

Comment: One of the permutations I tried.  I tried many, all unsuccessfully.

Comment: You can find a clone of IIS Manager here, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/master/JexusManager/Features/Main/BindingDialog.cs So not only the binding dialog but many others.

Comment: The list you are showing in IIS binding is IIS manager server certificates. You can load these certificates from local machine personal store or webhosting store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All answers return more certificates than IIS binding dialog.
I've compared the differences between certificates that are and aren't shown.
The difference seems to be
EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {**Server** Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.**1**)} - for those that are shown and
EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {**Client** Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.**2**)} - for those that aren't.
So basically IIS binding dialog shows you only relevant certificates (those that are meant to be used as Server Authentication).

It's a little bit tricky to get to that information in code world, here is how I did it:

```
        List<X509Certificate2> certificates = new List<X509Certificate2>();

        X509Store store1 = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        try
        {
            store1.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

            foreach (var certificate in store1.Certificates)
            {
                foreach (var extension in certificate.Extensions)
                {
                    if (extension.Oid.FriendlyName == "Enhanced Key Usage" && extension is X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension enhancedKeyUsageExtension)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in enhancedKeyUsageExtension.EnhancedKeyUsages)
                        {
                            if (item.FriendlyName == "Server Authentication")
                            {
                                certificates.Add(certificate);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            store1.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

They're in `StoreLocation.LocalMachine`.  Also, `X509Store` implements `IDisposible`, so it should be wrapped in a `using` statement.

```
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
{
     store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
     foreach (var x in store.Certificates)
     {
          radDropDownListIISCert.Items.Add(new RadListDataItem(x.FriendlyName, x.SerialNumber));
     }
}
```

Comment: It is only a partial answer. IIS does support certificates from the Web Hosting store, so not only the Personal store.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky:

First X509Certificate is obsolete use X509Certificate2 instead.
Second store is IDisposable so make sure to invoke .Close() or use "using" statement.

My solution:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
            var targetCollection = new List<X509Certificate2>();
            
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            var certificates = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>();
            targetCollection.AddRange(certificates);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //Handle that
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
```

Of course select proper fields from certificates in tempCollection to yours:

```
targetCollection.Select(c => new RadListDataItem(c.FriendlyName, c.SerialNumber));
```

Comment: This returned 18 certificates, whereas I have only 5 listed in IIS.  Any thoughts on what extra critieria IIS applies?

Comment: Use  others stores such as (StoreName.My) you can also use array with multiple storeNames as argument. Check in debug.
If you are unsure which to use checkout "Manage computer certificates" and "Manage computer certificates" in Windows(first is StoreLocation.CurrentUser and second .LocalMachine) . Enums StoreName should match folders in those managers but unfortunately this is not a 1:1 relation. Documentation not specify this  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename?view=netcore-3.1